# gradle 3.1.2 dependency on library's product flavor

Tags: android, gradle

Gradle version 3.1.2

I have a app and a module. The module has product flavors. When I make the app to depend on the module, gradle fails. Here is the gradle files,

The app gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        ...
    }
    buildTypes {
         release {
             ...
         }
    }
}

dependencies {
     implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
     ...
     implementation project(':mylibrary') <- this is the dependency added
}
```

The module gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        ...
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions 'api'
    productFlavors {
        v1_0 {
            dimension 'api'
        }

        v2_0 {
            dimension 'api'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    ...
}
```

The followings are the error generated by gradle,

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :mylibrary.
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :mylibrary.
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :mylibrary.
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :mylibrary.
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :mylibrary.
```

How do I make the app depend on the module using a product flavor?

implementation project(path: ':mylibrary', configuration: 'v1_0') is no longer work after gradle 3+

Answer (score 0):

Since Gradle 3.0 you have to use [missingDimensionStrategy](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.DefaultConfig.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.DefaultConfig:missingDimensionStrategy(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

That means you need to tell your `app` module which flavors to use for dimensions that your library has but your `app` module does not have.

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
    missingDimensionStrategy 'api', 'v1_0'
    ...
}
```

You can of course use the `missingDimensionStrategy` not only in your `defaultConfig` but also for `debug{}` and `release{}` buildTypes or to productFlavors, if you add some later.